# How do I fix this script to make it allow me to wall jump?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm relatively new to Godot and I want to make a platformer... a test one at last and I want to make the character do a wall jump. I followed one tutorial and the Godot Docs but got nowhere. I even tried Reddit. So, here's the script for it. Help will be much appreciated!

```
**extends CharacterBody2D

@export var speed = 400.0
@export var jump_speed = -1400.0
@export var wall_jump_push = 100

var gravity = 120
var wall_slide_gravity = 100
var is_wall_sliding = false
    
func _physics_process(delta):
    
    var collision = move_and_collide(velocity * delta)
    if collision:
        Input.get_axis("ui_up", "ui_down")
        
    var input_direction = Input.get_axis("ui_left", "ui_right")
    velocity.x = input_direction * speed
    
    move_and_slide()
    jump()
    wall_slide(delta)

func jump():
    velocity.y += gravity
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump") and is_on_floor():
        velocity.y = jump_speed
        
func wall_jump():
    if is_on_wall() and Input.is_action_pressed("jump"):
        gravity = 75.0
    else:
        jump()
        

func wall_slide(delta):
    if is_on_wall() and !is_on_floor():
        if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left") or Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
            is_wall_sliding = true
        else:
            is_wall_sliding = false
    else:
        is_wall_sliding = false
        
    if is_wall_sliding:
        velocity.y += (wall_slide_gravity * delta)
        velocity.y = min(velocity.y, wall_slide_gravity)**
```

This might be an easy fix, but I haven't found it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I see at a glance.

1. This code is wasted:

   ```
   var collision = move_and_collide(velocity * delta)
   if collision:
       Input.get_axis("ui_up", "ui_down")
   ```

   Here you are ignoring the return value of `get_axis`, and you do not use `collision` anywhere else.
2. `wall_jump` is never called. My guess is that you want to call `wall_jump` instead of `jump` in `_physics_process`.